# Как отменить растягивание grid на всю ширину родителя

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

Не могу разобраться с поведением контейнера grid. Мне нужно, чтобы в grid в середине был блок основного контейнера, а слева и справа от него были блоки aside на некотором расстоянии, которое я задаю `grid-column-gap: 10px;`. Причём контейнер по середине всегда должен растягиваться на 100%, до своего `max-width: 500px;`. И весь grid должен позиционироваться по середине страницы.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <aside class='box'>Левый aside</aside>
  <main class='main'>Главный контент</main>
  <aside class='box'>Правый aside</aside>
</div>

.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:250px;
}

.main{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}

.box{
  background: red;
}
```

Но в результате grid растягивается на всю ширину родителя и расстояние между блоками становится большое. Если указать `justify-content: center`, то поведение всё равно не такое, как нужно: теперь main уменьшается до ширины внутреннего содержимого.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную задачу и получить нужный результат.
Вот ссылка на песочницу:
https://codepen.io/v-mokrushin/pen/eYKLdgd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любые ограничения на элемент контейнера всегда устанавливаются самим контейнером, поэтому `width` и `max-width` мы убираем, а настройку `grid-template-columns` меняем на `200px minmax(auto, 500px) 200px`. Функция `minmax` принимает два аргумента: минимальное и максимальное возможное значение.
Для расположения в центре используем свойство для главной оси: `justify-content: center;`

Итоговый код:

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <aside class='box'>Левый aside</aside>
  <main class='main'>Главный контент</main>
  <aside class='box'>Правый aside</aside>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px minmax(auto, 500px) 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 10px;
  height: 250px;
}

.main{
  background: lightblue;
}

.box{
  background: tomato;
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь )

Answer (score 1):

Вы же задаёте врапперу `margin: 0 auto` - всё верно. Но чтобы это сработало, врапперу также нужно задать и некую максимальную ширину (чтобы он не растягивался во весь экран). Исходя из Ваших условий, ширина эта равна 920px: 500px + (10px * 2) + (200px * 2)

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height:250px;
  max-width: 920px;
}

.main{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}

.box{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <aside class='box'>Левый aside</aside>
  <main class='main'>Главный контент</main>
  <aside class='box'>Правый aside</aside>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, разобрался )